# How do I bind multiple controls to a single data source in .NET maui?

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui

I am working on a project and it's similar to a shopping cart using the MVVM scheme with help from the maui community toolkit. I have a list of items in an observable collection and upon tapping/clicking them I add them to a separate observable collection, let's call this the cart. For every item in the cart I want to display the name of the item and the amount of the item. By default it is set to 1 and the amount is displayed and bounded to an entry. I also have a stepper control that that has its value also bounded to this amount value so that the user doesn't have to type if they want to just increment by a couple and also not have to click too many times if they want to add like 20 of the item. This is all done in this code snippet here:

```
<CollectionView
    Grid.Column="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:InvoiceViewModel}}, Path=ItemsSold}">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ItemSold">
                                <Grid
                                    ColumnDefinitions="*,*,80">
                                    <Label
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}"
                                        Text="{Binding name}"/>
                                    <Entry
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        WidthRequest="150"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        BackgroundColor="White"
                                        Text="{Binding amount}"/>
                                    <Stepper
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Value="{Binding amount}"
                                        Increment="1"
                                        Minimum="0"
                                        Maximum="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:InvoiceViewModel}}, Path=inf}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

I have a button that when clicked displays the amount of the item so that I can debug some code. When I type a value in the entry say 5 and click the button it shows that the amount is 5. If I click the increase button in stepper and click the button it shows 2, default value 1 + 1, from this I see that there are two instances of the amount variable and this is not what I wanted. I wanted both the entry and stepper control to simultaneously update each other while also updating the bound data.
In my view model this is what I have:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new();
public ObservableCollection<ItemSold> ItemsSold { get; set; } = new();
public int inf = int.MaxValue;

public InvoiceViewModel() { }

public async Task GetItems()
{
    await InventoryService.Init();
    try
    {
        var items = await InventoryService.GetItems();
        if (Items.Count != 0) { Items.Clear(); }
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Unable to fetch inventory \n" + ex.Message, "OK");
    }
}

[RelayCommand]
private void AddToInvoice(Item item)
{
    if (item.unitPrice is null) { return; }
    ItemSold itemSold = new();
    itemSold.name = item.name;
    itemSold.description = item.description;
    itemSold.unitName = item.unitName;
    itemSold.unitPrice = (double)item.unitPrice;
    itemSold.amount = 1;
    ItemsSold.Add(itemSold);
}
```

I have tried including the two way binding mode to just the entry, to just the stepper and to both of them and none of them fixed the issue. Since the entry and the stepper doesn't exist until a gesture tap is done, I can't make a property in the view model and tag it with observable property tag from maui community toolkit. What am I missing to bind the amount data to the entry and stepper so that they share the same value all the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) to achieve this.

You can try to add an [ObservableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) attribute(`public int amount`) for the `ItemSold.cs`. Then it will generate an observable property `Amount`.
If you change the value of `Amount`,the UI will update itself(including the `Entry` and `Stepper`).

```
public partial class ItemSold:ObservableObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    public int amount;
}
```

Then in the `InvoiceViewModel.cs`, I added some fake data for `ItemsSold`.

```
public partial class InvoiceViewModel: ObservableObject
    {

        public ObservableCollection<ItemSold> ItemsSold { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemSold>();

        public int inf = int.MaxValue;

        public ICommand GetCommand { get; set; }

        public InvoiceViewModel() {

            ItemsSold.Add(new ItemSold { name ="Name 1",Amount = 1});
            ItemsSold.Add(new ItemSold { name ="Name 2", Amount = 1});
            ItemsSold.Add(new ItemSold { name ="Name 3", Amount = 1});
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void GetResult()
        {
           foreach (var item in ItemsSold)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------- item's name is: " + item.name +"<---> count is : " + item.Amount);

            }
        }

    }
```

At last,we need to bind the generated property `Amount` for the Entry and `Stepper`.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiCheckListviewApp.Views.SharedNumberPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel ="clr-namespace:MauiCheckListviewApp.ViewModes"
             xmlns:model ="clr-namespace:MauiCheckListviewApp.Models"
             Title="SharedNumberPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:InvoiceViewModel></viewmodel:InvoiceViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView  Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:InvoiceViewModel}}, Path=ItemsSold}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ItemSold">
                    <Grid
                                    ColumnDefinitions="*,*,80">
                        <Label
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Text="{Binding name}"/>
                        <Entry
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        WidthRequest="150"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        BackgroundColor="White"
                                        Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
                        <Stepper
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Value="{Binding Amount}"
                                        Increment="1"
                                        Minimum="0"
                                        Maximum="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:InvoiceViewModel}}, Path=inf}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <Button  Text="get result" Command="{Binding GetResultCommand}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

I also added a button to get the last result of the `ItemsSold` to verify the number, and the result was also in line with our expectations: Entry and Stepper shared the same amount.

Comment: Hi @SK99, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.